# How to add user defined function in U-Boot?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux, u-boot

Here i just want to add one function in u-boot. I need to call one function in start_armboot(). For example,

**This is hell.h header file.**

```
extern void hello(void);
```

**This is hell.c file.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<hell.h>

void hello(void)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

This hell.c is added into the common folder,and hell.h is added into the include folder. And then i include this hell.h into lib_arm/board.c. Finally i called hello() function from start_armboot() in lib_arm/board.c. Whenever i compiling it will show the error.

```
lib_arm/libarm.a(board.o): In function `start_armboot':
/home/davinci-evm/U-Boot/lib_arm/board.c:389: undefined reference to `hello'
make: *** [u-boot] Error 1
```

Is there any other procedure to add function in u-boot other than this? please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must modify the makefile inside common folder.

You can simply add

```
obj-y += hell.o
```